free gifts when buying items halal?
if someone bought a laptop and store A was cheaper and had a random scrath off style gift,that you would would get if u bought and store B didnt and you brought from store A (due to more deals and somewhat of the gist ie like the scratch off)and won prize from scratch off sytle gift, is it gambling, what to do with gift please provide evidence so i can rest assured

Don't worry. If there is a scratch and the seller tells you that the batteries are for free (which might have been included even without that scratch, you know how salesmen talk all over the world), it is his doing, not yours. So whatever he tells you about winning a price, if gambling or not, it is not you who is doing the gambling.

I guess this https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/84692/55518 applies also to your question.
